# Архитектура многопоточной модульной системы для .NET

Tags: многопоточность, архитектура, .net

Итак, к примеру есть игра - симулятор футбола.
Есть глобальный для сессии игры объект, который включает в себя список футбольных клубов, игроков в них и т.п. Данных тысячи и тысячи.

Корневой элемент игры примерно такой:

```
public async void Run(ISession session)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            dynamic result = await session.Go();

            if (result.ReadyToAction)
            {
                _gameControlEvent.WaitOne();
            }
        }
    }
```

Т.е. происходит обработка каких-то глобальных данных в игре, и дальше пользователь на это как-либо реагирует, и продолжается то же самое. Бесконечно.
Дело в том, что игра делается постепенно, и функционал расширяется. Поэтому есть некоторые модули (модуль - класс, которому на вход подается объект с данными, и он обрабатывает их. Может как читать, так и писать в этот объект), который собственно и занимаются обработкой этой большой информации.

```
public async Task<GoResult> Go()
    {
        ...

        foreach (var module in _modules.OrderBy(x => x.Priority))
        {
            results.Add(module.ProcessGameData(GameData));
        }

        ..

        CurrentDate = CurrentDate.AddDays(1);
    }
```

GameData - это и есть наш глобальный объект.

Вопрос в том, как лучше организовать подобную архитектуру?

Допустим, сейчас есть модуль "Транферы", а в будущем я добавлю модуль, который должен подождать результат обработки некоторых других модулей. Например, добавлю модуль - Новости, а он должен дождаться результата выполнения модулей Трансферы, Продление контракта, и т.п.
Т.е. как организовать такие зависимости между обработчиками.

Подразумевается, что каждый модуль может работать в **отдельном потоке.**
Может быть, уже есть какие-либо структурированные алгоритмы, схожие с этим?

Все почему-то отвечают на типичные многопоточный вопросы. я не про это спрашиваю.

Жесткая структура не нужна.
Нужно чтобы добавление модуля никак не меняло функционал системы.
Т.е вы пишите модуль, добавляете зависимости и все само работает

```
class TransferModule{ 
    TransferModule(INewsModule newsModule){
    //модуль трансфера отработает только после того, как завершиться выполнения модуля News     
    }
```

}

Comment: Ну так а чем конструкия lock(object) { } не устраивает? Или мутексы и семафоры по старинке?

Comment: Причем тут lock ? Я говорю, что нужен механизм определения модулей, да такой, чтобы можно было указать результат каких модулей он должен дожидаться, причем любой из этих модулей должен работать в любом другом потоке.и.т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вам для решения данной задачи будет достаточно прибегнуть к [Task.ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx)

Вот набросок.

```
    public interface IGlobalData
    {

    }

    public class GlobalData : IGlobalData
    {

    }

    public interface IModule
    {
        IGlobalData ProcessGameData(IGlobalData globalData);
    }

    public class Module : IModule
    {
        public virtual IGlobalData ProcessGameData(IGlobalData globalData)
        {
            return globalData;
        }
    }

    public class News : Module
    {
        public override IGlobalData ProcessGameData(IGlobalData globalData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("News");
            return base.ProcessGameData(globalData);
        }
    }

    public class Transfers : Module
    {
        public override IGlobalData ProcessGameData(IGlobalData globalData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Transfers");
            return base.ProcessGameData(globalData);
        }
    }

    public class AnotherModule : Module
    {
        public override IGlobalData ProcessGameData(IGlobalData globalData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AnotherModule");
            return base.ProcessGameData(globalData);
        }
    }

    class Continuations
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var globalData = new GlobalData();

            var rootTask = new Task<IGlobalData>(() => new Transfers().ProcessGameData(globalData));
            var newsTask = rootTask.ContinueWith(t => new News().ProcessGameData(t.Result));
            var anptherTask = newsTask.ContinueWith(t => new AnotherModule().ProcessGameData(t.Result));

            rootTask.Start();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Жесткая структура не нужна.
Нужно чтобы добавление модуля никак не меняло функционал системы.
Т.е вы пишите модуль, добавляете зависимости и все само работает

class TransferModule{ 
    TransferModule(INewsModule newsModule){
 //модуль трансфера отработает только после того, как завершиться выполнения модуля News  
    }

 
}

Comment: @IvanArtemov вам никто не запрещает сделать запуск модулей в цикле.

Comment: @IvanArtemov а сами модули подтянуть каким нить DI фреймворком.

Comment: Проблема не в том, что я не могу вызвать метод модуля. Проблема в том, что если у тебя их будет 50 нужно сделать так, чтобы время ожидания одних модулей от других было минимизировано. Ладно, я понял, тут не помогут

Comment: @IvanArtemov короче вы сами не знаете, что хотите, я верно вас понял? :)

Comment: Мстислав, вы понимаете, что я прошу не помочь мне вызвать из разных потоков какие-то методы ? Я хочу узнать лучшие практики для таких архитектур, где, образно говоря, строится граф зависимостей модулей и все это Execut'ится параллельно по наилучшему "маршруту", причем никакой поток не вызывает модуль несколько раз.

Comment: @IvanArtemov где в вашем вопросе указана инфа про "наилучший маршрут"? Где признаки этого наилудшего маршрута? В вашем вопросе указано, что вы не можете реализовать автоматическое встраивание модуля в конвеер.